# Deduce a series formula for product of Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Start with the arbitrary pair of Fibonacci numbers $F_{n+1}$, $F_n$ and apply the Euclidean Algorithm to it. Deduce a series formula for the product $F_{n+1}F_n$.

I use the formula, $F_{n+1} = F_n + F_{n-1}$, 
$F_1 = F_2 = 1$

When I find the $\gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)$ I get back the same result from the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a bit vague but perhaps this is what they want: the Euclidean algorithm will be
$$\eqalign{
  F_{n+1}&=F_n+F_{n-1}\cr
  F_n&=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\cr
  F_{n-1}&=F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}\cr
  &\quad\vdots\cr
  F_3&=F_2+F_1\cr
  F_2&=F_1\ .\cr}$$
Now multiply each equation by a suitable Fibonacci number to get
$$\eqalign{
  F_{n+1}F_n&=F_n^2+F_nF_{n-1}\cr
  F_nF_{n-1}&=F_{n-1}^2+F_{n-1}F_{n-2}\cr
  F_{n-1}F_{n-2}&=F_{n-2}^2+F_{n-2}F_{n-3}\cr
  &\quad\vdots\cr
  F_3F_2&=F_2^2+F_2F_1\cr
  F_2F_1&=F_1^2\ .\cr}$$
Now add all these equations.  If you look carefully you will see that most terms on the LHS also appear on the RHS and so they will cancel:
$$F_{n+1}F_n=F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2+F_{n-2}^2+\cdots+F_2^2+F_1^2\ .$$

**Comment**.  The reference to the Euclidean algorithm is pointless and misleading: we are not trying to find any GCDs.  All we are really using is the recurrence relation for the Fibonacci numbers.  In fact, the second last equation in my first set is not a correct application of Euclid since the "remainder" $F_1$ is not less than the divisor $F_2$.